# Seurity ramifications of ASP Session

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm looking into storing some security sensitive information (a users effective permissions for our web application) in a session-resident object, to reduce database queries while performing permissions checks throughout the app.

I understand that the session is stored server-side, and not directly accessible to the client under normal circumstances. ASP.net's other persistence mechanisms can be theoretically defeated, [by modifying viewstate or cookie values](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms10-070) client-side, but these kinds of cryptography implementation flaws should not expose session-state.

What degree of control over your server would an attacker need to modify data in a clients session-state? Assume they have a sessionID, and an ASPAUTH cookie.

For instance:

- A remote attack, like a modified POST or other handler call to a
  page?
- Would an attacker with programmatic access to IIS (WMI mabey?)
  be able to access and change session-state in the same or another app pool's memory?
- Would an attacker need to be able to post code to my app, in order to manipulate session memory?

I know these kinds of questions often rely on mistakes in my code, so by all means assume I've written the worst, most insecure code ever (I haven't, but...) and do things like change session in a constructor or life cycle event.

Answer (score 2):

Since we don't know exactly how your code is implemented, all we can do is guess.

First, Session should NEVER be used for security sensitive things.  Yes, it's true that a client can't directly read session, there are other factors to consider.

1. Session cookies are not, by default, encrypted and are passed as plain text.
2. Session Fixation attacks are easy to accomplish
3. If a session cookie is hijacked, or even guessed, then it doesn't matter what the users account is, they will get whatever security rights you assign via that cookie.
4. Session is unstable, and IIS can kill sessions whenever it feels like, so you end up with the situation where a user is still logged in, but their session is lost due to many possible reasons.  So now their security is also unstable.

There are many other, more appropriate ways to do what you want, Session is *NEVER* an appropriate method.

Other methods that would be appropriate include...

- Using the user data field of a FormsAuthentication ticket to store the information
- Using a custom Claim with a claims based authentication, like ASP.NET Identity, WIF, or IdentityServer.
- Using the asp.net Cache to hold the temporary information, based on identity (not session) and adding a cache eviction timeout.
- and many more...

Answer (score 1):

Session variable can be a security risk. It is always better to secure your session variable.

Few links you should take into consideration...

Securing Session State
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178201%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

http://www.dotnetnoob.com/2013/07/ramping-up-aspnet-session-security.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210993/Session-Fixation-vulnerability-in-ASP-NET

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/730/session-security-in-aspnet

I agree with Erik views.

regards